# dart, is it possible to de/serialize a function to/from json?

Tags: json, function, dart

Is it possible to define a function and de/serialize it to/from json? for example if I read in the file:

foo.json:

```
{
    name: 'foo',
    eventListener: (event){
       //Do stuff with event in here 
    }
}
```

then in the dart code read the json into a map and assign properties:

```
myObject.name = fooMap['name'];
myObject.onChange.listen(fooMap['eventListener']);
```

### Update

Thanks to Justin for the clarification, I'm trying to write a simple text based game using data driven design so its easy for other users to write their own additions and mods for it.

I want my program to be able to read in "genre pack" json files for example:

fantasy.json:

```
{
    name: 'Fantasy',
    description: 'Traditional fantasy concepts, knights, dragons, magic ... etc.',
    classes: [
        {
            name: 'Warrior',
            description: 'A melee fighter that wears heavy armor',
            passiveSkill: {
                name: 'Inner rage',
                description: 'When health drops below 10%, physical damage is increased by 100%.',
                impl: {
                    event: 'hpChange',
                    fn: (event){
                        if(event.hp < (event.hpMax / 10)){
                            event.character.physicalAttack += event.character.physicalAttack;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
        },
        // many more classes defined here...
    ]
}
```

So somewhere in a dart file when its parsed the genre json file it will hook up the event listener function to the characters 'hpChange' event. But from your comment it sounds like I'll hae to use a string to encode my event listener logic and have a special event handler creator function to parse that string and generate a series of nested functions to achieve the effect... maybe.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to serialize a function in Dart.

It's not directly possible to serialize a function to JSON in JavaScript either, though you could write it to a String, write that, and use `eval()` to read it back in, but that would only work in cases where you don't close over any free variables (variables that are declared outside the function, but accessed within it), because those might not be defined in the scope you deserialize to.

What you can do in a very limited set of cases is serialize the name of the function, and its arguments, and then manually lookup the function on the deserialization side either using mirrors or a lookup table. You still have an issue with free variables, but instead of the problem being that they aren't defined, the problem could be that they don't have the values you expect. It'll really be dependent on your application.

If you give a little more information about your use case, we might be able to offer other suggestions.